# Setting up alarm for X amount of times

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a question about alarms. Is it possible to set up an alarm so that it repeats X amount of times only? Like currently in the google docs, the setRepeating() repeats forever like shown in the code below:

```
 manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis, interval, pendingIntent);
```

where interval let's say is weekly in millis: `interval = 604800000;`

How do I make it so that it repeats only e.g. weekly for 3 times only? So something to set alarm X amount of times where X can be 3 or 5 or whatever the user sets?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you to store in preferences(or in another place) the amount of times the alarm has been trigger and cancel it if that amount passes the user set number of times.

Comment: Luksprog, How do I know when an alarm is triggered? I would like to save the alarm trigger and it's value but how do I know when the alarm will go off?

Answer (score 0):

store check value in SharedPreference ( called count), when alarm fire, increase it and store back to SharedPreference. When count = the integer that user sets. You cancle alarm X and set it again, do not forget set count = 0.

let the pendingIntent forward to BroadCastReceiver. When Alarm was trigger, then OnCreate() method called. Do some stuff follow your ideal.

Comment: How do I know when an alarm is triggered? I would like to save the alarm trigger and it's value but how do I know when the alarm will go off/what time the new alarm is set?

Comment: make your PendingIntent (of you alarm) nagavite to BroadCastReceive, when onCreate() method on this BroadcastReceive is called, that mean alarm is triggered.